# How to join strings in nested lists while maintaining list hierarchy?

Tags: python, string, list, recursion, nested

I have this list:

```
["a", "b", ["c", ["d", "e"], "f"]]
```

I wish to join the string elements in each list together while maintaining the list structure.

The expected behaviour is something like this:

```
>>> test_list = ["a", "b", ["c", ["d", "e"], "f"]]
>>> function(test_list)
["ab", ["c", ["de"], "f"]]
```

It would be very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978771/how-to-join-nested-list-of-strings-and-get-the-result-as-new-list-of-string), but it must able to handle an arbitrary number of nested lists.

I have tried to solve it using a recursive function but was not able to get the expected outcome.

Any tips?

Comment: It would be useful to include your current solution in the question, too.

Comment: use a stack to develope this

Comment: @sahasrara62 It's a bit more complicated than that, because there are levels that are split up into multiple sublists -- look at the `ab` and `f` parts of the top-level list.

Comment: @Barmar with recursion and stack you can achive this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right to try to use recursion to solve the problem. Here is how I designed my function:

```
sample = ["a", "b", ["c", ["d", "e"], "f"]]
desired = ["ab", ["c", ["de"], "f"]]


def mergeList(array):
    ret = []    #final array
    newEl = ""  #merged element

    for el in array:
        #If the element is a list, add our merged element and then
        #call the mergeList function on our list
        if type(el) == list:
            ret.append(newEl)
            newEl = ""  #clear the merged element so we can start over
            ret.append(mergeList(el))
        else:
            newEl += str(el)    #Add to the merged element

    #Final merge
    if newEl != "":
        ret.append(newEl)

    return ret

print(mergeList(sample))
```

The `mergedList` function will try to combine elements one by one until it reaches a list. When it finally reaches a list, it will first store the combined element to a new list and then repeat the process with the new list and store that result. After processing, it continues.

I made a crude diagram that I think can explain this. Each level represents a new recursive call on a smaller list. The bolded letters represent the variable `newEl` which contains the string that accumulates each element.

[image: Hierarchy Merge Example]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with recursion:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
d = ["a", "b", ["c", ["d", "e"], "f"]]
def combine(d1):
  return [i for a, b in gb(d1, key=str.__instancecheck__) 
          for i in ([''.join(b)] if a else map(combine, b))]

print(combine(d))
```

Output:

```
['ab', ['c', ['de'], 'f']]
```

Comment: @schwobaseggl `map()` returns a `map` object, not a list.

Comment: Oh right, I thought that was going into the return value. Complex list comprehensions can be confusing.... @schwobaseggl

Answer (score 0):

with recursion, you can achieve this way

```
l = ["a", "b", ["c", ["d", "e"], "f"]]


def nested2str(s):
    res = []
    tmp = []
    val = None
    for i in s:
        if type(i)==str:
            tmp.append(i)
        else:
            res.append(''.join(tmp))
            tmp = []
            val = nested2str(i)
            res.append(val)
    if tmp!=[]:
        res.append(''.join(tmp))
    return res

result = nested2str(l)
print(result)
```

output

```
['ab', ['c', ['de'], 'f']]
```

Answer (score 0):

**inductive reasoning**

Here's how I would write it using [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) -

1. if the input `t` is empty, return the empty result, `[]`
2. (inductive) `t` has at least one element. if the first element `t[0]` is a list, compute the recursive result and prepend it to the recursive result of the sub-problem `t[1:]`
3. (inductive) `t` has at least one element and the first element is *not* a list. If `t` has less than two elements, there is nothing to attempt to combine. Return `t`
4. (inductive) `t` has at least *two* elements. If the first element `t[0]` and the second element `t[1]` are strings, combine them and recompute the result
5. (inductive) `t` has at least two element and the first two elements cannot be combined. Return the first element, `t[0]` prepended to the recursive result of the sub-problem `t[1:]`

These easily encode into a simple python program, corresponding to the numbered comments below -

```py
def myfunc(t):
  if not t:
    return []                                            #1
  elif isinstance(t[0], list):
    return [myfunc(t[0])] + myfunc(t[1:])                #2
  elif len(t) < 2:
    return t                                             #3
  elif isinstance(t[0], str) and isinstance(t[1], str):
    return myfunc([t[0] + t[1], *t[2:]])                 #4
  else:
    return [t[0]] + myfunc(t[1:])                        #5
```

```py
input = ["a", "b", ["c", ["d", "e"], "f"]]
print(myfunc(input))
```

```py
['ab', ['c', ['de'], 'f']]
```

**less symbols, more words**

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutations, variable reassignments and other side effects. Python is a multi-paradigm language but broadly enables functional style through programmer discipline. Above we wrote a functional program but it is littered with many symbolic code bits that are commonplace in python programs. I think we could do a little bit better -

1. `t[0]` means "first element" and `t[1]` means "second element". Replacing these symbolic bits of code with names such as `first` and `second` can improve readability of our program and reduce the need for documentation
2. `t[1:]` means "all of `t` except the first element" and `t[2:]` means "all of `t` except the first two elements". We can use a name here too, such as `drop`
3. `not t` means "`t` is empty", adding the name `empty` here would help
4. `[x]+t` and `[x,*t]` and  means "prepend `x` to `t`. This could be a `prepend` function
5. finally, `myfunc` is not very descriptive, so how about something like `deepjoin`?

```py
def empty(t): return not t
def first(t): return t[0]
def second(t): return t[1]
def drop(t,n=0): return t[n:]
def prepend(x,t): return [x]+t
```

Now we can write `deepjoin` in a self-documenting way -

```py
def deepjoin(t):
  if empty(t):
    return []
  elif isinstance(first(t), list):
    return prepend(deepjoin(first(t)), deepjoin(drop(t, 1)))
  elif len(t) < 2:
    return t
  elif isinstance(first(t), str) and isinstance(second(t), str):
    return deepjoin(prepend(first(t) + second(t), drop(t, 2)))
  else:
    return prepend(first(t), deepjoin(drop(t, 1)))
```

The code functions exactly the same, but we traded a bunch of symbolic code for reusable functions with descriptive names. I think this program communicates its intent more clearly. Maybe you are very familiar with the symbolic code and prefer to keep it that way. That's OK too.

**evaluation visualization**

An understated advantage of functional programming is the ability to substitute any expression for its evaluated result. This allows us to define a decorator, such as `@trace`, where we can see exactly how `deepjoin` is working -

```py
from functools import wraps

def trace(f):
  frame = 0
  @wraps(f)
  def wrapper(*args):
    nonlocal frame
    space = " "*2*frame
    argstring = ", ".join(map(str, args))
    print(f"{space}-> [frame:{frame}] {f.__name__}({argstring})")
    frame = frame + 1
    result = f(*args)
    frame = frame - 1
    print(f"{space}<- [frame:{frame}]", result)
    return result
  return wrapper
```

Our `trace` decorator is generic and can be used with any function. We can use it with `deepjoin` by simply writing `@trace` on the line above our function definition -

```py
@trace
def deepjoin(t):
  # ...
```

Now when we run `deepjoin`, we see the "traced" output -

```py
print(deepjoin(input))
```

```
-> [frame:0] deepjoin(['a', 'b', ['c', ['d', 'e'], 'f']])
  -> [frame:1] deepjoin(['ab', ['c', ['d', 'e'], 'f']])
    -> [frame:2] deepjoin([['c', ['d', 'e'], 'f']])
      -> [frame:3] deepjoin(['c', ['d', 'e'], 'f'])
        -> [frame:4] deepjoin([['d', 'e'], 'f'])
          -> [frame:5] deepjoin(['d', 'e'])
            -> [frame:6] deepjoin(['de'])
            <- [frame:6] ['de']
          <- [frame:5] ['de']
          -> [frame:5] deepjoin(['f'])
          <- [frame:5] ['f']
        <- [frame:4] [['de'], 'f']
      <- [frame:3] ['c', ['de'], 'f']
      -> [frame:3] deepjoin([])
      <- [frame:3] []
    <- [frame:2] [['c', ['de'], 'f']]
  <- [frame:1] ['ab', ['c', ['de'], 'f']]
<- [frame:0] ['ab', ['c', ['de'], 'f']]
['ab', ['c', ['de'], 'f']]
```