# How do I trace a recursive function with a return function in it

Tags: python, function, recursion, trace, subroutine

I am trying to trace this recursive function, but I tried what I do usually but it did not work as when you return the function you need to add something to it. Can someone explain to me and give me a better understanding on how to trace functions like this using a table (or any other method) on the code below:

```
def NumberPatern(Value1,Value2,EndValue):
    print(Value1)
    if Value1<= EndValue:
        temp = Value2
        Value2 = Value1
        Value1 = Value1 + temp

       
        return NumberPatern(Value1,Value2,EndValue)+1
    else:
        return 0
```

using this as an input to the function

```
NumberPatern(1,1,12)
```

I am also given this table to trace the function:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretend you're the computer, interpreting this function line by line.

Every time the function is called, record the "Value1", "Value2", and "EndValue" it was called with in a new line in the table.

Fill in the "Temp" column every time `temp` gets assigned.

Fill in the "OUTPUT" column whenever the program produces output (i.e. calls `print()`.

When you hit a `return` statement, fill in the "RETURN" column, and step up a level.

---

For example:

Step 1: calling the function the first time

| Value1 | Value2 | Temp | EndValue | OUTPUT | RETURN value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  | 12 |  |  |

Step 2: Walk through the function until we hit the recursive condition, filling in data as we go:

| Value1 | Value2 | Temp | EndValue | OUTPUT | RETURN value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 12 | 1 |  |

Step 3: Since the function has been called again recursively, add the arguments it was called with to the table:

| Value1 | Value2 | Temp | EndValue | OUTPUT | RETURN value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 12 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 |  | 12 |  |  |

Step 4: Repeat the following two steps until you hit the base case
Step 5: When you hit the base case, fill in the returned value (since `temp` is never assigned in the base case, leave it blank)

| Value1 | Value2 | Temp | EndValue | OUTPUT | RETURN value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 12 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 12 | 2 |  |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 12 | 3 |  |
| 5 | 3 | 3 | 12 | 5 |  |
| 8 | 5 | 5 | 12 | 8 |  |
| 13 | 8 |  | 12 | 13 | 0 |

Step 13: Now walk back up the chain from where you were, and fill in the now-computed return values:

| Value1 | Value2 | Temp | EndValue | OUTPUT | RETURN value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 12 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 12 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 12 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 | 3 | 12 | 5 | 2 |
| 8 | 5 | 5 | 12 | 8 | 1 |
| 13 | 8 |  | 12 | 13 | 0 |

And this is the finished table.

Comment: This makes so much more sense, thank you for your kind help

Comment: So would it make 5 the final return value?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the result of the function to a variable. Then you can print all the columns of the table before returning.

```
def NumberPatern(Value1,Value2,EndValue):
    if Value1<= EndValue:
        temp = Value2
        Value2 = Value1
        Value1 = Value1 + temp

        output = NumberPatern(Value1,Value2,EndValue)+1
    else:
        temp = 'N/A'
        output = 0

    print(Value1, Value2, temp, EndValue, output)
    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

**algebra**

This is a good time to recall your algebra studies

```py
def NumberPatern(Value1,Value2,EndValue):
    print(Value1)
    if Value1<= EndValue:
        temp = Value2
        Value2 = Value1
        Value1 = Value1 + temp

        # focus here
        return NumberPatern(Value1,Value2,EndValue)+1
    else:
        return 0
```

The challenging part of this problem is that `Value1` and `Value2` are being reassigned. But we can rewrite it in a way that is far less confusing.

First replace `Value1` with its value -

```py
temp = Value2
Value2 = Value1
# Value1 = Value1 + temp
return NumberPatern(Value1 + temp,Value2,EndValue)+1
```

Now replace `Value2` with its value -

```py
temp = Value2
# Value2 = Value1
# Value1 = Value1 + temp
return NumberPatern(Value1 + temp,Value1,EndValue)+1
```

Finally replace `temp` with its value -

```py
# temp = Value2
# Value2 = Value1
# Value1 = Value1 + temp
return NumberPatern(Value1 + Value2,Value1,EndValue)+1
```

Now let's look at our revised program. And we will print *each* `Value1`, `Value2`, and `EndValue` at each step -

```
def NumberPatern(Value1,Value2,EndValue):
    print(f"v1:{Value1} v2:{Value2} end:{EndValue}")
    if Value1 <= EndValue:
        # temp = Value2
        # Value2 = Value1
        # Value1 = Value1 + temp
        return NumberPatern(Value1 + Value2,Value1,EndValue)+1
    else:
        return 0
```

```py
print(NumberPatern(1,1,12))
```

```
v1:1 v2:1 end:12
v1:2 v2:1 end:12
v1:3 v2:2 end:12
v1:5 v2:3 end:12
v1:8 v2:5 end:12
v1:13 v2:8 end:12
5                     # <- final answer
```

It's maybe not the exact output your homework is asking for but hopefully it shows you the headaches caused by variable reassignment used in recursive functions. The output is identical to Green's answer with the duplicate values removed.

**trace decorator**

In [another Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66715460/633183) I just wrote, I create a simple `@trace` decorator that can be used with any function. This decorator allows us to visualized the evaluation of complex functions -

```py
from functools import wraps

def trace(f):
  frame = 0
  @wraps(f)
  def wrapper(*args):
    nonlocal frame
    space = " "*2*frame
    argstring = ", ".join(map(str, args))
    print(f"{space}-> [frame:{frame}] {f.__name__}({argstring})")
    frame = frame + 1
    result = f(*args)
    frame = frame - 1
    print(f"{space}<- [frame:{frame}]", result)
    return result
  return wrapper
```

We can use it with your `NumberPatern` function by simply writing `@trace` on the line above. Note I also commented out your internal `print` statements -

```py
@trace
def NumberPatern(Value1,Value2,EndValue):
    # print(Value1)                         # <-
    if Value1<= EndValue:
        temp = Value2
        Value2 = Value1
        Value1 = Value1 + temp
        return NumberPatern(Value1,Value2,EndValue)+1
    else:
        return 0
```

Now when we run the function, we can see the "traced" output -

```py
print(NumberPatern(1,1,12))
```

```
-> [frame:0] NumberPatern(1, 1, 12)
  -> [frame:1] NumberPatern(2, 1, 12)
    -> [frame:2] NumberPatern(3, 2, 12)
      -> [frame:3] NumberPatern(5, 3, 12)
        -> [frame:4] NumberPatern(8, 5, 12)
          -> [frame:5] NumberPatern(13, 8, 12)
          <- [frame:5] 0
        <- [frame:4] 1
      <- [frame:3] 2
    <- [frame:2] 3
  <- [frame:1] 4
<- [frame:0] 5
5
```