# How do I use .join with a nested list?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I wanted to use ".join" to display the items in my list, each in a different line. I'm working with a nested list, so it doesn't really work the way I'm doing it. I'm a beginner at pyhton and so I was wondering if there actually is a way to solve this.

It shows "sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found" on line 10. How can I make this work?

```
product = str(input("What is the product? "))
quantity = str(input("What is the quantity? "))
sales = []

while product != "" and quantity != "":
    sales.append([product, quantity])
    product = str(input("What is the product? "))
    quantity = str(input("What is the quantity? "))

list = "\n".join(sales)

print(list)
```

This is just an exercise I found on youtube, I know it's pretty weird.

Comment: Show us a sample `sales` list and the desired output.

Comment: Possibly duplicate with: [Join in nested arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978771/how-to-join-nested-list-of-strings-and-get-the-result-as-new-list-of-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to loop through the list, formatting the inner lists, then join the result.

```
list = "\n".join(f"{a}: {b}" for a,b in sales)
```

That code took values in `sales` (the inner list), unpacked them to `a` and `b`, used  an f-string to format them and then emitted them for the `"\n".join()` operation.